# Why can't I include Win32 in my chef recipe?

Tags: chef-infra

This code at the beginning of my chef recipe:

```
require "win32/service"
include Win32
```

results in the following error:

```
No resource or method named `include' for `Chef::Recipe "install"'
```

This works in ruby, why doesn't it work in a chef recipe?

Thanks!

Comment: Because recipe is not pure Ruby. It is just a DSL that looks very like Ruby https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html If you want to write pure ruby - write it in library https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html or ruby_block https://docs.chef.io/resource_ruby_block.html

Comment: All in all, the real question is what do you try to do in your recipe ? Without more input it's hard to give any advice on how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Following code will work(in a recipe without the include/require),

`target_service = "FreeSSHDService"
if ::Win32::Service.exists?(target_service)
 Chef::Log.info target_service + "Found!"
else
 Chef::Log.info target_service + "NOT Found!"
end`

The leading :: tells it not to look in the Chef namespace.

**Reason for include not working,**

In normal, non-Chef Ruby, you can include other classes in your own by using the include syntax; for example, include Opscode::OpenSSL::Password. Used in a recipe, however, the recipe compiler will try to find a provider for a resource of type “include” and it will fail.